How to dynamically create an enum based on user input in Rust
I'm making a game that allows you to choose the number of players you're playing against; we use the number of players to create a player turns enum that we then progress through.
enum MetaGamePhase{
    ChoosePlayerCount,
    ConfirmLibrary,
    ChooseFirstTurn,
    InitialDraw,
    MulliganChoice,
    ActiveGame,
    EndGame,
    DeclareWinner,
    None
}

// need to set the contents of this based on the players choosing the player count
enum Turn{
    Player1,
    Player2,
    Player3,
}

enum Action {
    ProgressPlayerTurn
}

fn reducer(mut state: GameState, action: Action) -> GameState {
    match action{
        Action::ProgressPlayerTurn => GameState{
            turn: {
                use Turn::*;
// will also need to set this dynamically based on the enum
                match state.turn {
                    Player1 => Player2,
                    Player2 => Player3,
                    Player3 => Player1,
                }
            },
            ..state
        }
    }
}

struct GameState{
    turn: Turn,
    meta_game_phase: MetaGamePhase
}


How would I do this in rust?

Enums are a compile-time construct only. You should use an integer value for current player and number of players instead.

Rust is not Javascript, it has a clear separation between compile-time and runtime. Creating enums can only be done at compile-time and so can't be affected by runtime values.

What is the benefit to using this sort of cyclic enum rather than just a ring buffer or priority queue that you can push and pop from as appropriate?

In Rust, enums are a compile-time construct, so you cannot dynamically create or modify enums based on runtime input. but you can achieve similar functionality by using other constructs such as vectors or integer values to manage the dynamic aspects of your game state

The answer is you can't do that, and you should use a different language feature.
